# Decode encoded Russian characters from url to actual characters in BHO

Tags: c#, c++, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters, bho

While navigating to a non-ascii url: "[http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Елизавета_I](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0_I)" inside IE, the url received at OnBeforeNavigate2 inside BHO is encoded to

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0_I

What is this encoding type ?
How can i convert this url back to original non-ascii url in c# or c++?

Comment: Search for "percent encoding URL". Also read here - http://www.url-encode-decode.com/ - "For example, the string: François ,would be encoded as: Fran%C3%A7ois (The "ç" is encoded in UTF-8 as two bytes C3 (hex) and A7 (hex), which are then written as the three characters "%c3" and "%a7" respectively.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly this is not possible inside BHO,

So, I changed my approach to do this inside managed code using URI class.

Uri.UnescapeDataString(https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0_I)

Which returns "[http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Елизавета_I](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0_I)".

Answer (score 2):

Every `%XX` tuple is one byte in hexadecimal notation (and the percent sign). So %D0 is a byte with (unsigned) value 208. It should be easy to convert this in both languages.

The result will be the URL in UTF8 encoding.

Comment: Do c# has a utility class which i can use for utf-8 conversion specially for this case ?

Comment: @ArnoldS Converting UTF8 to what exactly? (The percent-hex-part to pure bytes is unrelated to UTF8. The result is UTF8, not the percent-stuff)

Comment: do you mean %D0%95%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0_I part of above url is UTF-8 ? or entire URL  is encoded ?

Comment: @ArnoldS The %D0... part is "url encoding" of your UTF8 text. After convertig %D0... to bytes, you have pure UTF8 text. And ideally you shouldn't convert this to anything then. UTF8 is comparable to ASCII, but pure old ASCII can't handle Russian characters (or any non-english stuff) and is not used anymore (other than in very old programs that are still used for some reason).

Comment: How can i convert %D0.. part of above string to bytes ? Do i have to iterate entire string get the %D0.. part, Convert it and replace inside original url ? Or is there a mechanism in c# which i can use ?